# How to restrict values of np.random with some non-normal distribution to an interval?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am seeking a random array with non-normal distribution and values in some defined interval, say, from -100 to 100.  I cannot see how to do that with the arguments available in numpy.random.name_of_distribution.  For example,

```
k = np.random.noncentral_chisquare(1, 50, 100)
```

has arguments (degrees of freedom, noncentrality and size).  The range of values seems to depend on where I set that noncentrality; in other words, changing it to 90 moves the top end of the distribution up to 120 or 130.

```
np.random.exponential(10,100)
```

is producing a range from 0 to 60 or so.  Must one be clever and rescale the output algebraically, or is there a quicker fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input distribution has a bounded range, then rescaling algebraically is the simplest solution.  However, your chosen example of a `noncentral_chisquare` is unbounded above.  In that case you'll need to use something like an acceptance/rejection scheme to throw away values larger than some upper bound. That can be done either before or after algebraic rescaling, as long as you adjust the rescaling parameterization appropriately.

There are other alternatives if you're generating the target distribution directly via [inversion sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), but acceptance/rejection is going to be your best bet with library functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the inversion sampling.

Comment: @JKelly If you want to go that route, then you need to solve algebraically for lower and upper bounds of the Uniform(0,1) that correspond with your target lower and upper bound on the outcome.  Then generate U's by scaling to that range and inverting.  One way or another, it all comes down to scaling or acceptance/rejection.